# Linkedin get user feed

Tags: http, linkedin-api

I try to get my linkedin feed using this API :

https://linkedin.api-docs.io/v1.0/feed/42Hm9SaY2p2CGwPzp

I try to use this request : "GET /voyager/api/feed/updates" with this shell code :

> curl --request GET \   --url
>   https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/feed/updates \   --data '{}'

But I get this response : "CSRF check failed". I understand why linledin respond this but how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2):

You missing headers, see API docs here: https://linkedin.api-docs.io/v1.0/feed and explanation how get headers here: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-browser-cookies-and-voyager-api-to-scrape-linkedin-via-python-25e4ae98d2a8

API docs a bit outdated, data output format might be different, this at least true for messaging/conversations, not sure about feed

In regards of headers I suggest to try apify.com and extract them in real time from browser instance (run puppeteer, login to LiN, get headers, save them)
Phantombuster will not allow you to use your own code so not very useful

Comment: Do not post only the links

Comment: Phantombuster does allow you to use your own code. You simply have to enable "developer mode" in your settings. Our developer documentation is available here https://hub.phantombuster.com/